# Does libboost-python have a multiarch support for armhf? (DEBIAN)

Tags: compilation, debian, shared-libraries, cross-platform

**Short**

Does `libboost-python` have a multiarch support for `armhf`?

**Elaborate**

I want to install `libboost-python` on a amd64 bit machine, for `armhf` cross compilation purposes. Thus it should be `armhf`. However, in the dependency chain `libboost-python` will try to install `python`, and since the first package is `:armhf`, `python` also should be `armhf`. Which cases a failure, because one of the post scripts runs the `python` interpreter, and it cannot be run since the interpreter is `armhf` while the machine is `amd64`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've investigated, `libboost-python` Debian package does not support multiarch. A possible soultion for the problem in the post is using `qemu` in order to emulate a "native" environment for building packages.